# How do I make my php not send form data to mysql if it doesn't meet criteria?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make my website display an error message if any if the form fields are empty,I thought I did do that,but it doesn't output any error message and it just adds empty rows into my DB columns. I should add this is sort of mix and matched,I did put effort into this, but I didn't make it from scratch or anything.Anyway any help is greatly appreciated!

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$VarErr = $PavErr = $AdErr = $PkErr = $KiekErr = "";
$Vardas = $Pavarde = $Adresas = $Pk = $Kiekis = "";

?>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Dailės parduotuvė</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stilius.css">
        </head>
<body class="content "> 


<div class="container">
                   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Kauno dailė</a>

                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="Visos.html">Visos prekės</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="Uzsakymas.php">Užsisakymas</a>
                                </li>                                                                      
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>


</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content sm-4">
<h2> Pirkimo paaiškinimas/Prekių kainos </h2>
<br>
<p>Mūsų parduotuvėje kainos sekamos pagal prekių kodus,tad,įsitikinkite,ar teisingai juos suvedėte!</p>
<h1>Kainos:</h1>
<p>Pieštukas: 2&euro;<br>
Dažai: 3&euro;<br>
Teptukas:2&euro;<br>
Darbo reikmenys:1&euro;</p>
<h1>Pateikę užsakymą,padarykite banko pavedimą šiam gavejo kodui:LT******************</h1>
</div>


<div class="content sm-4 text-center">
<h2>Užsakymo forma</h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  

  <p class="text-center">Vardas</p><br>
  <input type="text" name="Vardas" value="<?php echo $Vardas;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $VarErr;?></span>

   <p class="text-center">Pavarde</p><br>
  <input type="text" name="Pavarde" value="<?php echo $Pavarde;?>">
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $PavErr;?></span>

   <p class="text-center">Adresas</p><br>
  <input type="text" name="Adresas" value="<?php echo $Adresas;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $AdErr;?></span>

  <p class="text-center">Pk</p><br>
  <input type="number" name="Pk" value="<?php echo $Pk;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $PkErr;?></span>

  <p class="text-center">Kiekis</p><br>
  <input type="number" name="Kiekis" value="<?php echo $Kiekis;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $KiekErr;?></span>
  <br>


  <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Užsisakyti">
</form>



</div>
</div>


    <!-- PHP KODAS  -->
<?php




if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Vardas"])) {
    $VarErr = "Įveskite vardą";
  } else {
    $Vardas= test_input($_POST["Vardas"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Vardas)) {
      $VarErr = "Galima vesti tik su raidėmis"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Pavarde"])) {
    $PavErr = "Įveskite pavardę";
  } else {
    $Pavarde = test_input($_POST["Pavarde"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Pavarde)) {
      $PavErr = "Galima vesti tik su raidėmis"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Adresas"])) {
    $AdErr = "Įveskite adresą";
  } else {
    $Adresas= test_input($_POST["Adresas"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Pk"])) {
    $Pk = "Įveskite prekės kodą";
  } else {
    $Pk = test_input($_POST["Pk"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Kiekis"])) {
    $KiekErr = "Įveskite kiekį";
  } else {
    $Kiekis = test_input($_POST["Kiekis"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$database = "uzsakymas";

try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
} 
catch(mysqli_sql_exception $ex){
    echo 'database connection error';
}
//insert
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {

    $Vardas = $_POST['Vardas'];
    $Pavarde = $_POST['Pavarde'];
    $Adresas = $_POST['Adresas'];
    $Pk = $_POST['Pk'];
    $Kiekis = $_POST['Kiekis'];

    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO uzsakymai (Vardas,Pavarde,Adresas,Pk,Kiekis)VALUES('$Vardas','$Pavarde','$Adresas','$Pk','$Kiekis')";
    try {
        $insert_result = mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query);

        if($insert_result){
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
                }else{
                    echo'Data not Inserted';
                }   

            }
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            echo 'Error Insert'.$ex->getMessmessage();
        }
}

?>  

    <div class = "footer py-5 bg-secondary">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Validate the form before submitting it. Go with js if its client-side validation or php if you want to validate on the server-side.

Comment: Validation [with JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) and Validation [with PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp)

Comment: It feels like I saw this exact question a couple of times recently. (Along with the horrible `test_input()`, the local variables not being used, and the error variable ignored). Where does this code got copy&pasted from?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Is there any way you could show me how my code is supposed to look ? As I said my main need is that it doesn't insert the data,if all the fields aren't filled out and in the necessary criteria

Comment: You set lots of variables like `$AdErr` and `$KiekErr`, but you never check them before performing the `INSERT`.

Comment: Also, you should not use `htmlspecialchars` when storing data in the DB. It should be used only when displaying data on a web page.

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into SQL, to protect against SQL-injection.

Comment: This is supposed to be form that submits data to a DB and checks for errors.I'm not entirely aware what you mean by prepared statements,though I think I have some clue,I mainly just want to see how to it work with the basic idea I have right now. Also I got all those Err variables from a w3 tutorial.